# Shrink-wrap flexbox with wrapping flex-items so it can be centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with wrapping contents. How can I shrinkwrap the flexbox to its contents? The root problem I'm trying to solve is to center the flexbox. This image describes my issue:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Is it possible in pure CSS? I don't know beforehand if the flexbox will wrap to 1, 2 or 3 columns. The width of the elements is known. The height would preferably be unknown, but if it makes it a lot easier, I can decide on a constant height.

Neither `width:min-content`, `width:max-content`, `width:fit-content` nor `inline-flex` appear to solve the problem.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oznts5bv/

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px dashed magenta;
}

.container div {
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created an two examples: with `display: flex;`, and `display: grid;`. The second option will probably suit you better:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px dashed magenta;
  max-width: min(100%, 302px);
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="100" max="600" value="302" oninput="document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach(el => el.style.maxWidth = 'min(100%, ' + this.value + 'px)')">
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I try to decrease the available width in your examples (by resizing the browser window) below 302px, both examples break. The flexbox example behaves like the one in my question, and the grid example goes off-screen. Any idea how to solve one of those issues?

Comment: Yes, already solved with help `max-width: min(100%, current max-width in px);`

Comment: Your grid example solves my problem perfectly, thank you!